# Completely Self Sustaining Aquatic Environment in a Sealed Jar

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium, aquatic-plants, algae, brineshrimp

I recently got the idea into my head to create an entirely self sustaining aquatic environment in a (large) sealed jar. I'd like to include:

1. A layer of soil and gravel at the bottom
2. A large number of plants for natural chemical cycling
3. Algae
4. Brine Shrimp
5. Copepods
6. Maybe a few larger shrimp (enough to create a self sustaining colony)

What ratios of Algae to Brine Shrimp to Copepods to Shrimp biomass should I establish in the environment? What minerals/chemicals should I ensure are present before I seal the jar shut? What plants should I use? Am I crazy for thinking this could actually work?

Comment: @KarlRichter search for 'bottled ecosystem' there are lots of hits. Some with and without fish.  I remember you used to be able to buy these to put on your desk.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Thank you, I was under the impression that real isolation is incredibly hard to achieve, which is apparently not the case.